# Passing parameters from same program in spark scala without main

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am learning spark with scala and this might be a basic question, but i am struggling, can some one please help me? I have a scala program like below:

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION IBECDateAdd AS 'com.my.UDFs.IBECDateAdd'")
sqlContext.sql("set mapred.create.symlink=yes")
sqlContext.sql("set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat")
sqlContext.sql("use mydb")

val  trigdate=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT '2017-04-02'""").first.get(0)
val  OUTPUT=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT '/whildpsace/spark/Ankur_op'""").first.get(0)
val  COL_DELIM=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT '|'""").first.get(0)

val  Step1=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT gmt_dt AS gmt_dt FROM mydb.events WHERE gmt_dt BETWEEN IBECDateAdd('dd', -1,  """+trigdate+ """) AND IBECDateAdd('dd', 1,  """+trigdate+ """) LIMIT 10""")
Step1.registerTempTable("Step1");


Step1.registerTempTable("Results");

val columns= Results.columns.mkString("COL_DELIM")
val valuesRdd= Results.map(r=>r.mkString("COL_DELIM")).map(a=>(2,a))

val schemaRdd= sc.parallelize(Seq((columns)),1).map(a=>(1,a))
valuesRdd.union(schemaRdd).sortByKey(true, 1).map(x=>x._2).saveAsTextFile("OUTPUT");
```

In the above code, i am not able to replace the values trigdate, OUTPUT and COL_DELIM. Could you please let me know what is the right way to replace them in sql?

Thank you!

Comment: Im sorry, following statement missed in the above code:

Comment: val  Results=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT gmt_dt AS gmt_dt FROM Step1 WHERE gmt_dt BETWEEN IBECDateAdd('dd', -1,  """+trigdate+ """) AND IBECDateAdd('dd', 1,  """+trigdate+ """) LIMIT 10""")

Comment: Results.registerTempTable("Results");

Comment: Never Mind, I got the solution, I need to place the """+trigdate+ """ in single codes, like '"""+trigdate+ """'.